# Is a Custom Dimension or data type the reason why the price dimension isn't showing up on my scatterplot with Google Analytics 4 Explorer?

Tags: google-analytics-4, google-datalayer

Can't report prices of item viewed. Help!

Noticed that I couldn't "Explore" a basic scatter plot on one of my client's GA4 Explorer.

I wanted to make a scatterplot: X = `view_item`, Y = `price` and every point would be `item_name`. So I can see if there is any relation with price and items viewd. When I make the report, the price dimension is (not set).

I have two possible reasons, but I'm asking for help:

- Somebody set a Custom Dimension called "price" (same name and letters of price parameter within items, so it may be overwriting the ecommerce data?
- The price sent within the ecommerce.view_item data layer is not a string, but a number.

This is the actual structure of the `dataLayer.push()` of the `view_item` event

```
{
  "pageName": "xxx",
  "pageType": "product",
  "ecommerce": {
    "items": [
      {
        "item_name": "xxx",
        "price": 39992,
        "item_brand": "xxx",
        "item_category": "xxx",
        "item_category_2": "xxx",
        "currency": "USD",
        "item_stock_status": "In stock",
        "item_sale_product": "No",
        "item_reviews_count": "0",
        "item_reviews_score": "0",
        "plugin": "plugin"
      }
    ]
  },
  "event": "view_item"
}
```

Does it sound familiar to you? Do you need more info?

I tried archiving the custom dimension created, I'm waiting for data. But I wanted to know if there's reason for that behavior.